# Contagem de Dias de uma data

Tags: c#, winforms

Precisava que esse parâmetro contasse os dias até a data que eu digitar por exemplo (31/12/2016) conforme mostra a imagem anexada, porém ele está retornando apenas a quantidade de dias que foi digitado no caso 31 dias e não o total de dias até aquela data que no caso seria 366 dias.
Alguém pode me dar alguma dica de como fazer essa contagem retornando o total de dias até a data digitada?

Observação: O retorno da quantidade de dias será em uma label (lblTotalDias.Text)

```
int iTotal = 0;

if (iDia < iMes)
{
            iDia = 0;
            iTotal++;

            if (iDia < 30)
            {
                iDia++;
                iTotal++;

                if (iMes == 2 && ((iAno % 400 == 0) 
                    || (iAno % 4 == 0 && iAno % 100 != 0)) && iDia == 28)
                {
                    iTotal++;
                    iDia = 31;
                }

                if (iMes == 2 && !((iAno % 400 == 0) 
                    || (iAno % 4 == 0 && iAno % 100 != 0)) && iDia == 27)
                {
                    iTotal++;
                    iDia = 31;
                }

                if ((iMes == 1 || iMes == 3 || iMes == 5 || iMes == 7 
                    || iMes == 8 || iMes == 10 || iMes == 12) && iDia == 30)
                {
                    iDia++;
                    iTotal++;
                }
            }
                iMes++;
                iTotal++;
        }
            iDia++;
            iTotal++;

            lblTotalDias.Text = (iDia - 1) + " DIAS";
  }
```

---

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi o critério que chegou nos 31 dias.

Comment: Não era para ser assim: ` lblTotalDias.Text = (iTotal - 1) + " DIAS";`?

Comment: Eu digitei a data 31/12/2016 e no caso era pra me retornar os dias do começo do ano no caso 01/01/2016 até 31/12/2016 que seriam 366 dias, porém ele não esta me retornando os 366 dias como eu gostaria e sim somente os 31 dias que foi digitado não sei se conseguiu entender

Comment: @isaque ele me retorna os 31 dias também

Comment: era para ele calcular a distancia em dias da data digitada até a data de hoje?

Comment: @isaque era pra ele calcular o total de dias da data digitada por exemplo 31/12/2016 até a data inicial do começo do ano que seria 01/01/2016 que seriam 366 dias

Comment: Faltou dizer a lógica clara, está muito confuso, mas, não precisa de quase nada de código, a estrutura DateTime já faz boa parte desses cálculos

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Obrigado, eu aproveitei o código usando algumas regras de dia e mes e utilizei o DateTime ai consegui fazer o calculo sem retornar erro.

Answer (score 2):

Isso pode ser facilmente feito com o `DateTime` e o `TotalDays`:

```
DateTime diaEscolhido = new DateTime(iAno, iMes, iDia);  //Cria a variável de datetime com a data escolhida
string dias = ((int)(DateTime.Now - diaEscolhido).TotalDays).ToString(); //Faz a operação para saber a diferença de dias com o dia atual
lblTotalDias.Text = "DIAS: " + dias;
```

Para checar se o ano é bissexto, use o `IsLeapYear`:

```
lblAnoBissexto.Text = DateTime.IsLeapYear(iAno) ? '366' : '365';
```

**Referencias:**

- [Estrutura DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx).
- [TotalDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays(v=vs.110).aspx).
- [isLeapYear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.isleapyear(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode primeiro verificar o parâmetro de ano.

```
//Declarando variáveis que retornaram a diferença de dias
int anofinal, mesfinal, anofinal, total;
//Data que você recolherá
DateTime dt = new DateTime(ano, mes, dia);
//Data que servirá como referência;
DateTimeRef dtref = new DateTime(anoref, mesref, diaref);
if (ano == anoref)
{
   continue;
}
else
{
  total = ((ano - anoref)*365)
}
```